# How to handle a linq query that returns zero rows and have it return decimal value?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

When a this function is given an id that in SQL returns 0 rows I get the error below:

*The null value cannot be assigned to a member with type System.Decimal which is a non-nullable value type.*

What is the best way to modify the query to prevent this. I am pulling the value from a different table than I am querying here, so I would like to be able to handle giving it a "bad" id.

```
    public decimal GetSumOfValuesForAccount(Guid companyId)
    {
        return (from o in _context.Details
                where o.CustomerID == companyId
                select o).Sum(p => p.SomeValue.GetValueOrDefault());
    }
```

Returns the error:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should be able to either return:

```
return (from o in _context.Details
                where o.CustomerID == companyId
                select o).Sum(p => p.SomeValue) ?? -1.0;
```

or

```
decimal? temp = (from o in _context.Details
                where o.CustomerID == companyId
                select o).Sum(p => p.SomeValue);
return temp ?? -1.0;
```

The `??` operator will check for null, and if null, return the next value.

Comment: I know about null coalescing operator, but it was still failing. But based upon your comment, I removed the GetValueOrDefault while using it and it works. Not sure why that made the difference though.

Comment: @Speedy2171 - That's because you can't do an operation like `.GetValueOrDefault()` on a null reference. That means there is no 'row' that satisfies your condition, and you need to let Linq handle it itself.